# Not all elements in a foreach are being used

Tags: perl, snmp

I have the following code segment that should be retrieving data via snmp:

```
my $pl = Parallel::Loops->new(100);
$pl->share( $infohash, \%bounds);
$pl->foreach( \@servArray, sub {
    my $server = $_;
    my ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(-hostname => $server, -community => $community_string);
    if ($error) { die ("$error") };
    if ($session) {
    my $return = snmpwalk(
        snmp => $session,
        oids => $oidhash{$server},
        -mycallback => sub {
            my ($s, $host, $key, $val) = @_;
            my @tempArray = split (/,/, $key);
            $bounds{$host}{$tempArray[0]}{$$val[0][0]}{$tempArray[1]} = $$val[0][1];
        }
    );
    $session->close();
    }
    else {
        die ($error);
    }
});
```

$infohash is a nested hashref structured like this:

```
        'hostname' => {
                            'hard_drives' => {
                                               'serial_number' => 1
                                             },
                            'system' => {
                                          'service_tag' => 1
                                        },
                            'ip_address' => {
                                              'ip_address' => 1
                                            },
                            'memory' => {
                                          'serial_number' => 1
                                        }
                          },
```

And %oidhash contains a corresponding list of oids, and looks like this:

```
      'hostname' => {
                          'system,service_tag' => '1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.1.300.10.1.11.1',
                          'hard_drives,serial_number' => '1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10893.1.20.130.4.1.7',
                          'memory,serial_number' => '1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.1.1100.50.1.23.1',
                          'ip_address,ip_address' => '1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.1.1100.90.1.11.1'
                        },
```

Now, all elements of this work fine, except for the system/service_tag bit.  This is the output that I get, from @return:

```
$VAR1 = \{
        'memory,serial_number' => {
                                    '10' => '874F72F8',
                                    '12' => '874F73DF',
                                    '11' => '874F73CD',
                                    '1' => '874F7242',
                                    '8' => '874F746C',
                                    '2' => '874F7474',
                                    '3' => '874F7477',
                                    '5' => '874F743F',
                                    '7' => '874F73D3',
                                    '6' => '874F747F',
                                    '9' => '874F73D9',
                                    '4' => '874F7237'
                                  },
        'ip_address,ip_address' => {
                                     '1' => '<public IP>',
                                     '2' => '10.245.27.145'
                                   },
        'system,service_tag' => {},
        'hard_drives,serial_number' => {
                                         '6' => '9XF05FE0',
                                         '4' => '9XF05LXB',
                                         '1' => '9XF05GM0',
                                         '2' => '9XF05FHH',
                                         '3' => '9XF05FE8',
                                         '5' => '9XF04JNK'
                                       }
      };
```

Obviously, this means the snmpwalk isn't retrieving all the data as it should, but I'll be damned if I can find a reason why.  If I snmpwalk the service tag OID manually, it does retrieve data, so it's not the OID, and it's not anything I can find, because all other data is retrieving.

Comment: Does it work if you just loop normally instead of using Parallel::Loops?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion I failed to mention earlier is to Data::Dumper your data structure in the callbacks. This line here:

```
$bounds{$host}{$tempArray[0]}{$$val[0][0]}{$tempArray[1]} = $$val[0][1];
```

you could Dumper these out one at a time:

```
print Dumper($bounds, $tempArray, $val );
```

just to verify that each is doing what you expect it to. I can't shake the idea that your getting punked by all the blind derefrencings:

```
 $$val[0][1]
```

I'm thinking you may over 'over-dereferencing' there. Remember you want the code to be as clean and readable as possible, the more levels of [][] [({})] you get, the more chances of problems and the harder to find they become.

Comment: It's simply not iterating over the service tag.  Dumping those shows all the same info, but in a not as nice format.  As for the $val, that's how Parallel::Loops gives output - as a multi dimensional array ref.